# Why do Tailwind classes not work and how can I fix the issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind classes, but they don't work. I have installed Tailwind and modified the settings.

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz1Tu.png)
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BAdo.png)

What should I do to make sure classes will work?

Comment: It's more helpful if you add your code inline, instead of as an image. It would also help for you to the `tailwind.config.js`, index.css` and `package.json` files in your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't set up post-CSS, try the following method

```bash
npm install -D postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```